# spark df.write quote all fields but not null values

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a csv from values stored in the table:

```
 | col1   | col2   | col3  |
 | "one"  | null   | "one" |
 | "two"  | "two"  | "two" |

hive > select * from table where col2 is null;
 one   null    one
```

I am getting the csv using the below code:

```
df.repartition(1)
  .write.option("header",true)
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("quoteAll", true)
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .csv(S3Destination)
```

Csv I get:

```
"col1","col2","col3"
"one","","one"
"two","two","two"
```

Expected Csv:WITH NO DOUBLE QUOTES FOR NULL VALUE

```
"col1","col2","col3"
"one",,"one"
"two","two","two"
```

Any help is appreciated to know if the dataframe writer has options to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go in a udf approach and apply on the column (using `withColumn` on the repartitioned datafrmae above) where possiblity of double quote empty string is there   see below sample code

```
 sqlContext.udf().register("convertToEmptyWithOutQuotes",(String abc) -> (abc.trim().length() > 0 ? abc : abc.replace("\"", " ")),DataTypes.StringType);
```

> `String` has `replace` method which does the job.

```
val a =  Array("'x'","","z")
println(a.mkString(",").replace("\"", " "))
```

will produce `'x',,z`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.
I'm looking for a way where the dataframe writer has options not to add doublequotes to null values since I did not want to manipulate the csv.

Comment: sorry AFAIK I'm not aware of such option in built. above approach should work

Comment: if you are okay please accept as owner. it will be pointer to other users as well. Thanks!